# How to adjust magnification when mounting camera on microscope

Tags: optics

I apologize in advance if this is the wrong site for this question.  If this is the wrong site, would some kind soul point me towards the correct site?

I have a couple of Vision Engineering TS4 microscopes in my lab (both purchased used from eBay).  One came with a camera attachment with a completely unknown camera mounted.  No documentation, no cables, no power supply.  Luckily, the microscope has a standard "C-mount" attach point.

The TS4 microscope has an optical zoom range from x6 to x40.  This is a great range when working with surface-mount components on circuit boards.  These microscopes project the image onto a view screen rather than forcing the user to sit hunched over a pair of eyepieces.  Current listing on eBay: [Vision Engineering TS4 Stereo Dynascope](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Vision-Engineering-TS4-Stereo-Dynascope-30-Day-No-Hassle-Warranty/322914386626)

I removed the existing camera and instead installed a 2.0 MP camera, also purchased from eBay.  [Wireless Control 1080P HDMI HD Industrial Lab C-mount 2.0MP Microscope Camera US](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Wireless-Control-1080P-HDMI-HD-Industrial-Lab-C-mount-2-0MP-Microscope-Camera-US/311759645479).  I've used these cameras previously when modifying simple lens-based microscopes with great success.

The problem that I'm having is that the image on the monitor driven by the camera has far too much magnification as compared to the optical screen mounted on the microscope.  So much so that the resulting image simply can't get small enough.

What I know about optics and lenses might fit on the head of a very small pin.  I don't have any idea how or what to change to bring the image size seen by the camera down to something similar to what is displayed on the native view screen.

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: In the old days before computers , we had precise gratings. we would measure the spacing in the final image and know the total magnification.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this particular microscope, but usually, the magnification is determined by the objective lens of the microscope, and less so by the camera (although changing the camera position with respect to the tube lens will vary the magnification slightly).

more precisely, the magnification is determined by the ratio of focal lengths between the tube lens and the objective lens (in an infinity-corrected microscope, which is pretty much the standard).

I suggest you do some reading on geometric optics and infinity-corrected microscopes to expand your understanding.

Hope this helps.